# Trying to change MKPointAnnotation colour but losing the title

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkpinannotationview

I am trying to change my pin colour to purple, when I do it I lose the title though. Code is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;

    //init the location manager
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation=YES;

    self.userGeoPoint=self.message[@"userLocation"];
    self.pinView = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];

    self.pinView.title=self.message[@"fromUser"];
    self.coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.userGeoPoint.latitude, self.userGeoPoint.longitude);
    self.pinView.coordinate=self.coord;
    //use a slight delay for more dramtic zooming
    [self performSelector:@selector(addPin) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
}

-(void)addPin{

    [self.mapView addAnnotation:self.pinView];
    [self.mapView selectAnnotation:self.pinView animated:YES];
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(self.coord, 800, 800);
    [self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];

}

-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotationPoint
{
    if ([annotationPoint isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])//keep the user as default
        return nil;

    static NSString *annotationIdentifier = @"annotationIdentifier";
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotationPoint reuseIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];
    pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
    //now we can throw an image in there

    return pinView;
}
```

I tried setting the title property for MKPinAnnotation but there isn't one. Is there anyway I can get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `viewForAnnotation`, you need to set `canShowCallout` to `YES` (it's `NO` by default):

```
pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
```

---

A couple of unrelated points:

1. It looks like you have a property named `pinView` of type `MKPointAnnotation` that you are using to create the annotation object in `viewDidLoad`.  Then in `viewForAnnotation`, you have a local variable also named `pinView` of type `MKPinAnnotationView`.  Although there is no naming conflict here, it causes and implies some conceptual confusion.  `MKPointAnnotation` is an annotation *model* class while `MKPinAnnotationView` is an annotation *view* class -- they are completely different things.  It would be better to name the annotation property `pin` or `userAnnotation` for example.
2. This comment in `viewForAnnotation`:

   ```
   //now we can throw an image in there
   ```

   seems to imply that you could set a custom image in the view at this point.  Setting a custom image in a `MKPinAnnotationView` is not recommended since that class is designed to display default pin images in one of three colors.  To use a custom image, create a plain `MKAnnotationView` instead.

Comment: Thanks for this! Works now. Thanks for your pointers also. I will modify the code.

Answer (score 1):

The `pinColor` property was deprecated in iOS 9. From iOS 9 onwards you should use `pinTintColor` which takes a `UIColor` rather than a `MKPinAnnotationColor`.

Old:

`MKPinAnnotationView *view = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:nil];
view.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;`

New:

`MKPinAnnotationView *view = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:nil];
view.pinTintColor = [UI Color purpleColor];`

There is more information available in the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPinAnnotationView_Class/).

Answer (score 1):

I just upgrade to ios 10, apple changed the api.

pinColor no longer in use, instead, use tintColor

New:

```
 MKPinAnnotationView *view = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:nil];
 view.tintColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the pin title will be displayed when the user taps it:

*If the value of this property is true, a standard callout bubble is shown when the user taps a selected annotation view. The callout uses the title and subtitle text from the associated annotation object.* 
(  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkannotationview/1452451-canshowcallout )