# Set MapKit pins with different colors

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapkit, mkannotation

I am new in iOS and I implemented a MapKit with static markers from different arrays types and they are working fine , I am trying to put pins that come from shops array to be blue for example , and pins that come from community read , etc .. I have no idea about how to do this
at all , they are all in red in the map and my goal is to change the color for every array of pins

here what I have tried :

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class myMapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    var shops = [Shops]()
    var communities = [Community]()
    var cyclists = [Cyclist]()
    var circuits = [Circuit]()
    
    @IBOutlet weak var myMap: MKMapView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       
        shops.append(Shops(id: 0, title: "Shop1", latitude: 36.553015 , longitude: 10.592774))
        shops.append(Shops(id: 0, title: "Shop2", latitude: 35.499414 , longitude: 10.824846))
        communities.append(Community(id: 0, title: "community1", latitude: 37.276943 , longitude: 10.934709 ))
        communities.append(Community(id: 0, title: "community2", latitude: 35.427828 , longitude: 9.748186 ))
        circuits.append(Circuit(id: 0, title: "circuit1", latitude: 33.773035 , longitude: 10.857805 ))
        cyclists.append(Cyclist(id: 0, title: "cyclist1", latitude: 35.785118 , longitude: 10.000871 ))
        createShopsAnnotations(locations: shops)
        createCircuitsAnnotations(locations: circuits)
        createCommunityAnnotations(locations: communities)
        createCyclistsAnnotations(locations: cyclists)
    }
    
    func createShopsAnnotations(locations:[Shops]){
        for location in locations {
            let annotations = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotations.title = location.title as? String
            annotations.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.latitude as! CLLocationDegrees , longitude: location.longitude as! CLLocationDegrees)
            myMap.addAnnotation(annotations)
        }
    }
        
    func createCircuitsAnnotations(locations:[Circuit]){
        for location in locations {
            let annotations = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotations.title = location.title as? String
            annotations.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.latitude as! CLLocationDegrees , longitude: location.longitude as! CLLocationDegrees)
            myMap.addAnnotation(annotations)
        }
    }
    
    func createCommunityAnnotations(locations:[Community]){
        for location in locations {
            let annotations = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotations.title = location.title as? String
            annotations.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.latitude as! CLLocationDegrees , longitude: location.longitude as! CLLocationDegrees)
            myMap.addAnnotation(annotations)
        }
    }
    
    func createCyclistsAnnotations(locations:[Cyclist]){
        for location in locations {
            let annotations = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotations.title = location.title as? String
            annotations.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.latitude as! CLLocationDegrees , longitude: location.longitude as! CLLocationDegrees)
            
            myMap.addAnnotation(annotations)
        }
    }
}
```

I have headed some tutorials but I was not able to apply them on my example.

Comment: To set a color check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29318882/3565291

Comment: That question uses `MKPinAnnotationView` instead of `MKPointAnnotation ` and just sets `pinAnnotationView.canShowCallout = true` and `pinAnnotationView.tintColor .purple`

Comment: I am sorry , I saw the code of the solution , but I really do not know where to place it in my code , I started learning swift 2 weeks ago , I still feel lost

Comment: where is my pinAnnotationView??

Comment: `let pinAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView()` inside the `viewFor` delegate. I will post an answer, but I recommend starting with easier tasks to learn programming. Otherwise it can be very frustrating because it's a lot of concepts.

Comment: thank you so much , I will wait the answer

Comment: IMHO, if only supporting iOS 11 and later, you should _not_ implement `viewFor` method. View annotation configuration code belongs in the view annotation class, not inside the view controller. And even if you do need to support old OS versions, in the spirit of “separation of responsibilities”, the `viewFor` method should just be instantiating the appropriate annotation view, not doing any configuration of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic idea is to make an annotation view type to render the correct color. So, assume for a second that you have four annotation types (see below), then you might have an annotation view type like so:

```swift
class AnnotationView: MKMarkerAnnotationView {
    override var annotation: MKAnnotation? { didSet { update(for: annotation) } }

    override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        update(for: annotation)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }

    func update(for annotation: MKAnnotation?) {
        switch annotation {
        case is Shop: markerTintColor = .blue
        case is Community: markerTintColor = .cyan
        case is Cyclist: markerTintColor = .green
        case is Circuit: markerTintColor = .red
        default: break
        }
    }
}
```

And then you would have your view controller register that annotation view for your map view:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapView.register(AnnotationView.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier)

    ...
}
```

Note, when you register an annotation view type like this, you do *not* want to implement any `mapView(_:viewFor:)` method. Since iOS 11, that delegate method is not needed/recommended any more.

Anyway, that annotation view type assumes you have four types of annotations. I'd personally make `Shop`, `Community`, `Cyclist` and `Circuit` just be annotation types, e.g.

```
class Shop: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    let id: Int
    dynamic var title: String?
    dynamic var subtitle: String?
    dynamic var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

    init(id: Int, title: String, subtitle: String? = nil, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
        self.coordinate = coordinate

        super.init()
    }
}

// repeat for the other three types
```

And then, when I want to add them to my map:

```swift
shops.append(Shop(id: 0, title: "Shop1", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 36.553015, longitude: 10.592774)))
shops.append(Shop(id: 0, title: "Shop2", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 35.499414 , longitude: 10.824846)))
communities.append(Community(id: 0, title: "community1", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.276943 , longitude: 10.934709)))
communities.append(Community(id: 0, title: "community2", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 35.427828 , longitude: 9.748186)))
circuits.append(Circuit(id: 0, title: "circuit1", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 33.773035 , longitude: 10.857805)))
cyclists.append(Cyclist(id: 0, title: "cyclist1", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 35.785118 , longitude: 10.000871)))

mapView.addAnnotations(shops + communities + circuits + cyclists)
```

---

Alternatively, you might have one annotation type:

```swift
enum PlaceType {
    case shop, community, cyclist, circuit
}

class Place: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    let id: Int
    let type: PlaceType
    dynamic var title: String?
    dynamic var subtitle: String?
    dynamic var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

    init(id: Int, type: PlaceType, title: String, subtitle: String? = nil, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.id = id
        self.type = type
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
        self.coordinate = coordinate

        super.init()
    }
}
```

You'd then instantiate these places:

```swift
var places = [Place]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapView.register(AnnotationView.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier)

    places = [
        Place(id: 0, type: .shop, title: "Shop1", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 36.553015, longitude: 10.592774)),
        Place(id: 0, type: .shop, title: "Shop2", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 35.499414 , longitude: 10.824846)),
        Place(id: 0, type: .community, title: "community1", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.276943 , longitude: 10.934709)),
        Place(id: 0, type: .community, title: "community2", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 35.427828 , longitude: 9.748186)),
        Place(id: 0, type: .circuit, title: "circuit1", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 33.773035 , longitude: 10.857805)),
        Place(id: 0, type: .cyclist, title: "cyclist1", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 35.785118 , longitude: 10.000871))
    ]
    mapView.addAnnotations(places)
}
```

And your annotation view type would then use this `type` parameter:

```swift
class AnnotationView: MKMarkerAnnotationView {
    override var annotation: MKAnnotation? { didSet { update(for: annotation) } }

    override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        update(for: annotation)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }

    func update(for annotation: MKAnnotation?) {
        guard let annotation = annotation as? Place else { return }

        switch annotation.type {
        case .shop: markerTintColor = .blue
        case .community: markerTintColor = .cyan
        case .cyclist: markerTintColor = .green
        case .circuit: markerTintColor = .red
        }
    }
}
```

This results in:

[image: map]

Comment: this is the answer.