# SwiftUI custom street color in native Map

Tags: xcode, swiftui, mapkit, apple-maps

I need to change streets colors in a native Apple Map?

It's possible? Any solution?

Thanks.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65646649/

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct API to do that.

Starting with iOS 16, you can experiment with the new blend modes of overlays to change color.

For a demo, see the WWDC 2022 video: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc22/10035

Blend mode documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkoverlayrenderer/3941884-blendmode

Here is a nice article: https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-online/mapping/blend-modes-are-here-and-theyre-pretty-awesome/